# Javascript - how to safely evaluate expressions for auto-complete?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, eval

I'm adding an auto-complete feature to my javascript console (the script is running on a remote browser).

My approach is to evaluate the expression where the caret is, and if the evaluation yield an `object` - suggest it's list of properties for auto-complete. For instance (where `|` is the caret position):

```
document.|
```

in this case I evaluate `var evalExp = document;` then iterate it's members `for (var prop in evalExp)`  to create a list of auto-complete suggestions.

The problem is, if the expression I'm evaluating contains functions or assignments, such as: 

`count++`, 

`e.click()` or 

`alert('Some message')`, 

I wouldn't want it to be executed, since it changes the browsers state instead of just evaluating and returnning an object.

Therefore, I want to avoid evaluating any expressions if they call functions, or if they contain assignment operators.

**Questions:**

Are there any other kinds of expressions I should avoid evaluating?

What alternative ways are there to create the suggestion list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative way to create the suggestion list is to get the object model as a string, split by periods, and loop over the last object's properties. For example...

```
var line = "document.body.getElementsBy",
objs = line.replace(/[\(\{\[]+.*?[\)\}\]]+/g, '').split(/[^\w\-]/),
lastObj = objs[objs.length - 1],
currentObj = window,
i = 0;

if (objs[0] === 'window') {
    objs.splice(0, 1);
}

objs.splice(-1, 1);

while (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(objs[i])) {
    currentObj = currentObj[objs[i++]];
}

for (var prop in currentObj) {
    if (prop.indexOf(lastObj) === 0) {
        console.log('Auto complete:', lastObj, 'with', prop);
    }
}

/* Outputs:
Auto complete: getElementsBy with getElementsByTagName
Auto complete: getElementsBy with getElementsByTagNameNS
Auto complete: getElementsBy with getElementsByClassName
*/
```

Your final code will be more complex but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually dealing with all the parsing stuff in Java code, and already have a script that works. My current concern is being able to run the script with 100% assurence that I'm not alternating the DOM context during the process.

Comment: What do you mean by alternating the DOM context?

Comment: I mean, changing the state of objects while eveluating the script line for auto complete. Consider these scripts: `count = 3`, `element.click()` or `alert('ALERT')` - I wouldn't want them to execute or pop up an alert when I'm trying to build an auto complete list...

Comment: The terms I used in this sentence might not be accurate, hope now you get what I mean.

Comment: The only way I can think of to manage an autoComplete like this is to build a library of definitions to check against and add to that library dynamically whenever a use assigns a variable or some such. That way nothing gets eval'd and you end up saving a ton of resources (I would think).

Comment: It's the best method, in my opinion.

Comment: @Makaze in IE11 `currentObj.hasOwnProperty` seems not to work on `document`. `currentObj[objs[i]]` works however.

Comment: I concur with Makaze that this code works. None of the code @Elist mentions gets executed, but there properties are suggested in the auto complete list. +1.